# Demonstrating the erc1155 data

Tags: web3js, nft, erc-1155

how can I get the data of my erc1155 on the front/backend? I don't know which libraries and which functions to use?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERC1155 gives you a `function uri(uint256 _id) external view returns (string memory);` function that gives you URL for metadata of an asset. The metadata is a JSON file. See [EIP-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) for more details.

About how you'll access the data; is how you'll invoke the contract function. You can use any known library; ( [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/) being a popular one) to call the `uri` function, and then make an HTTP call to the URL and get desired data.